# Can I select a link based on the first part of an attribute and then send it a click event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using the following selector:

```
$('a[data-href="/C003Q/History"]').click(function(){        
   alert("clicked");
});​
```

This finds the link with the above data-href attribute and clicks it. However I need to do something slightly different. What I have is a variable that has something like the following stored:

```
/Admin/Contents/Edit?pk=0103000&rk=0047
```

How can I take the four characters after the rk= and search for a link that has a data-href that starts with "/C" followed by those four characters and send a click to it?

Comment: You're not clicking the link. ``.click(function(){ ... })`` associates a click handler, ``.click()`` actually triggers the event..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use split and use both start with and end with selector.

```
arr = url.split('rk=');
result = arr[arr.length-1];   

$('a[data-href^="/C"][data-href$=' + result + ']').click(function(){
   alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: Ahh so there's no way I can do this by just adding "/C" + result and then looking for something that starts with that? For example here I would be looking for data-href="/C0047" followed by anything.

Comment: You can use * to search match any where in the string, data-href*="/C0047